# setTimeout functions double even when cleared first

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have images in the img/ directory (1-13.jpg) and I need to loop through them. the `#next_container` is supposed to `stop();` the loop if it already `start();`ed and change the `src` to the `next();` image then `start();` it again, but when I click on `#next_container` it runs the `next();` function as expected but for some reason `stop();` doesn't stop the old timeout and I end up with **two** `start();` functions running which causes the images to change faster and when it's `stop();`ed the `#next_container` is supposed to only get the `next();` image but for some reason the loop `start();`s. the same happens for `#prev_container`.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="imgs" src="img/1.jpg" onload="start();">
    <div id="next_container" style="display: none;">
        <span id="next">&#x2771;</span>
    </div>
    <img id="player" src="" style="display: none;">
    <div id="prev_container" style="display: none;">
        <span id="prev">&#x2770;</span>
    </div>
    <p id="count">1 / 13</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
// the images array holds sources for all the images
function next(){
    var element = document.getElementById("imgs");
    var num = Number(element.src.split("/").slice(-1)[0].split(".")[0]);
    if (num == images.length){
        element.src = "img/1.jpg";
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "1 / 13";
    } else {
        num++;
        element.src = images[num-1];
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = num.toString()+" / 13";
    }
}
function prev(){
    var element = document.getElementById("imgs");
    var num = Number(element.src.split("/").slice(-1)[0].split(".")[0]);
    if (num == 1){
        element.src = "img/13.jpg";
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "13 / 13";
    } else {
        num--;
        element.src = images[num].src;
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = num.toString()+" / 13";
    }
}
function start(){
    window.timeout = setTimeout("next()", 3000);
    document.getElementById("player").src = "img/pause.png";
    document.getElementById("player").onclick = function(){ stop(); };
    document.getElementById("next_container").onclick = function(){ stop(); next(); start(); };
    document.getElementById("prev_container").onclick = function(){ stop(); prev(); start(); };
}
function stop(){
    clearTimeout(window.timeout);
    document.getElementById("player").src = "img/play.png";
    document.getElementById("player").onclick = function(){ start(); };
    document.getElementById("next_container").onclick = function(){ next(); };
    document.getElementById("prev_container").onclick = function(){ prev(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the onload fires for each image you load. Example showing it.

```js
function start() {
  console.log("I AM CALLED");
}

function loadNext () {
  document.querySelector("img").src = "http://placekitten.com/400/300"
}

window.setTimeout(loadNext, 2000);
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" onload="start()" />
```

So you call  `next(); start();`, next changes the source so it will cause the `"onload="start()"` to fire and than you call `start()`. There is your two timers. Remove the start() after the next and prev calls.

Comment: I see so all I needed to do is `<script>start();</script>`. I thought that onload runs when the whole page is loaded only

Comment: @joezak body onload would only fire once